# How to give path to Styles folder, one directory up, asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, obout

i am using Obout combobox, its styles folder is one directory up, when i give its path in FolderStyle, its detected by Visual Studio and the combobox with new style appears, but when i run it on browser, it gives the error
Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: the ../ from the current directory should work right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For referncing style sheet or javascript files you can do something like this

```
../Styles     to go one step back and find Styles folder
../../Styles  to go two step back and find Styles folder
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to use the ~ character:

< obout:ComboBox runat="server" ID="ComboBox1" FolderStyle="~/ComboBox/styles/black_glass" />